# Can I make partial screenshot of page by chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Can I make partial screenshot of the page after load in Chrome browser? It's the best if I can make screenshot of the chosen DOM element. I think about normal client JavaScript browser code, without any extensions.

Comment: Did you make any research at all? Because a simple Google search lead me to [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)

Comment: Wow, thanks it's should be great. Yes I was looking for that, but unfortunately didn't find anything working.

Answer (score 0):

In your Google Chrome Browser press F12 followed by Ctrl+Shift+p and search for capture full size and click enter.

An in-built full-size screenshot tool provided by Chrome

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I believe OP wants a screenshot made with JS, for their users, not for himself.